# Mocha cant load module because it is a webpack external

Tags: javascript, webpack, mocha.js

I have an external set in my webpack.config.js that some of my ES6 modules import:

```
// webpack config:
externals: {
  'ExternalConfig': JSON.stringify(require('./config/config.dev.json'))
}
// ES6 modules:
import ExternalConfig from 'ExternalConfig'
```

When I run mocha tests on modules that import the external as a module then Mocha throws Error: Cannot find module 'ExternalConfig'

Is there any way I can pass the external to mocha to fix this issue?

Comment: I assume that you are misunderstanding the `externals` option. [According to the docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals), the `externals` option should only be used in conjunction with the `output.library` option. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am passing dev/prod config file path to the application. The app is static and the correct config path is bundled depending on the npm script and env setting.

Comment: What about using a `resolve.alias`?

Comment: Thanks jhnns. You are right the externals is not the place to load config. I will use node server on dev/prod to load the config file based on env. Updating answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by jhnns the webpack externals is not the place for loading config. I now load my config file based on the node process env global. This means mocha does not need to run webpack config and works as expected.

Comment: What if you don't have a Node server? I'm getting the same error, as I was doing exactly the same as you before, loading some config from a json depending on the environment I was deploying to, but we are serving this as a standalone over an nginx server .. 

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Better you can require the json at the beginning of the webpack like,

```
const devConfig = require('./config/config.dev.json');

 // webpack config:
 externals: {
   'ExternalConfig': JSON.stringify(devConfig);
 }

 // ES6 modules:
 import ExternalConfig from 'ExternalConfig'
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks RM-123. Mocha does not run the webpack config so it thinks it needs to find it in node_modules.